# An $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ function with two plateaus of different heights and a valley

Tags: functions, polynomials, exponential-function, graphing-functions, applications

I am looking for a $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ function $f$ with two plateaus of different heights and a valley.

The function has a minimum for $x=a$ and $f(a)=b$.

The first (the one for smaller $x$) plateau has height $d$ and the second plateau (the one for larger $x$) has height $c$, see this figure:

[image]

One constraint is that $c>b \land d>b$; no constraint is set on the relative heights of the plateaus: it can be $c\lt d$ (as in the previous figure) or $c\geq d$.

I had a look at [Function to show 2 peaks with different magnitudes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112827/function-to-show-2-peaks-with-different-magnitudes) but it requires a periodic function while I do not need a periodic function.

I also had a look at [camel hump with trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229752/camel-hump-with-trigonometry) and in particular at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229838/10799 but I was not able to find suitable $a$, $b$, $k1$ and $k2$ to get two humps.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=2.5-\frac{1}{x^2e^x+0.5}$$
In general:
$$f(x)=a-\frac{k}{(x+m)^{b}e^{cx+n}+d}$$
With some parameters seems to do the trick